# C# Form not accepting user input (acting frozen)

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been working with Forms in a console application recently for a project. I'm launching and refreshing my window in a new thread as seen here:

```
public void runGame()
{
  Thread windowthread = new Thread(windowRender);
  threadRunning = true;
  windowthread.Start();
}

public void windowRender()
{
  if(!windowOpened)
  {
     window.gamewindow.Show(); //window.gamewindow is a typical Windows Form
     window.gamewindow.Refresh();
  }
  while (threadRunning)
  {
    if(shouldRender)
    {
      window.gamewindow.Refresh();
      shouldRender = false;
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I launch the Form (window.gamewindow, a typical Windows Form) it doesn't accept user input, I can't even click the Maximize, Minimize, and Exit buttons and it cannot be dragged around the screen. It is able to render and refresh successfully (as shown in the image). Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and what I can do to fix it? [Screenshot of working render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpl1x.png)

Comment: "working with Forms in a console application" - you really should post part of code that you use for that (and if possible location to article where you've learn how to do that).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry about that, here you go: http://pastebin.com/T5Q5dEhJ

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any waiting before subsequent refresh, when exactly would you expect the form to have time to refresh for user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are blocking windows messages by not calling `Application.DoEvents()`.
Insert it between the `while` block and I guess it'll help.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to know for sure what the problem is. But most likely, it is simply that you've failed to call `Application.Run()` in the thread that is hosting the window.

You are only updating the window when the flag `shouldRender` gets set to `true`, but that provides no mechanism to process user input, nor to redraw the window and its elements due to situations outside your control (such as the window being reshown after being obscured partially or entirely by other windows, etc.).

If you want to host a window in a new thread, you should do something more like this:

```
public void runGame()
{
    Thread windowthread = new Thread(windowRender);

    // STA threads are required for Winforms components!
    windowthread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

    threadRunning = true;
    windowthread.Start();
}

public void windowRender()
{
    // The Run() method will return with the gamewindow Form
    // is closed. You should notify the windowing system of a need
    // to redraw the Form by calling Invalidate() on it.
    Application.Run(window.gamewindow);
}
```

Most likely, you don't need the `threadRunning` or `shouldRender` flags at all.